# I have a problem inserting more than 255 chars per column into an Excel file using INSERT INTO OPENROWSET from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, openrowset

I am getting an error while exporting data from SQL Server to an already created `.xlsx` file using `openrowset`.

It works fine most of times, but when the data comes in of the field as a large string, while inserting into Excel, it shows this error:

> The statement has been terminated, string or binary data would be truncated.

Data gets inserted into table, but while inserting in Excel, this error appears. Please help me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the error mentions "data would be truncated", you should be provide a longer string value into a placeholder or field that has a smaller storage size.

For example, the source field may have data type nvarchar(max) and in your SQL development or where a mapping exists, you assing the values into a smaller data size type. For example, in source table you have a string value 5000 characters, but during the process it is assigned to a nvarchar(4000) then a data truncation will occur

I would suggest you to check data mappings in your statements

Comment: Yes, char size is 4000, Solution worked for me:
Inserted dummy data into the first 8 rows of the Excel speadsheet for the large field columns , which fixed the problem. But I need some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Regedit: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel

In Regedit, set the "TypeGuessRows" value on this path to a value greater than 8, for example 100000.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncRGJ.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).