# Insert into OPENROWSET erorr-String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When exporting data from `SQL Server` to `Excel`, when a field size is large e.g. `nvarchar(4000)` or `nvarchar(max)` might cause the error below:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\DataExport.xls;', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT * FROM DataExport_Table
```

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: `When exporting data from SQL Server to Excel` this is a true ??

Comment: When exporting data from SQL Server to Excel. this is a true -->>Yes

Comment: Did you just read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477920/i-have-a-problem-inserting-more-than-255-chars-per-column-into-an-excel-file-usi and repost the answer?

Comment: Actually  this guy is my friend and we both are looking for ans. and we both get above ans but we want better ans. adding  row is not good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution worked for me:

Inserted dummy data into the first 8 rows of the Excel speadsheet for the large field columns , which fixed the problem.